# Renaming multiple files with batch script (.bat)

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script to rename all files in a folder.
The naming convention of the files vary, some of them have a `.` before the extension, for example: `xxxx.xxx.ext`, some don't.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to keep the name of the file intact but remove everything after the first . and replace it with .txt

To that end I thought I would be able to do one of two things:

1. Use RegEx
2. Use a wildcard (or something similar) to target everything after the first `.`

I'm not too sure how to implement either. So far I have the following:

```
@echo off
set local enabledelayedexpansion

set "regEx=\.(*)"
set "extension=.txt"

for %%F in (*.*) do (
    echo Processing file: %%F
    
    set"newName=%%F"
    set"newName=!newName:%regEx%=%extension%!"
    echo !newName!
    :: ^This is only used for testing whilst the below if statement is commented out

    if not "%%F" == "!newName!" (
        echo Renaming file to: !newName!
        ren "%%F" "!newName!"
)

endlocal
```

When changing the `set "regEx=\.(*)"` variable to set `"regEx=.ext"` it will rename all files from `.ext` to `.txt` However the issue persists with `XXXX.XXX.ext` only being renamed to `XXXX.XXX.txt` (but at least I know the rest of the script works!)

I've looked into both possibilities I outlined above my code but am unsure how to implement either. If anyone could point me in the right direction, id appreciate it!

Comment: I would assume a simple one line batch file could do that: ```@For %%G In (*.*) Do @For /F "EOL=? Delims=." %%H In ("%%G") Do @If Not Exist "%%~H.txt" (Echo Processing file: "%%G"& Echo Renaming file to: "%%~H.txt"& Ren "%%G" "%%~H.txt" 2>NUL)```.

Comment: Support for regex in batch is very weak generally and the `set` statement does not recognise it.